# Unable to detach or destroy AWS Network Interface created via CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I have been successfully creating and destroying this AWS CloudFormation stack https://github.com/jacekdalkowski/aws-cf-eks-min/blob/main/eks-min.yaml recently, but today deletion process failed and I cannot clean it up since then.

According to logs, it failed when deleting (in order):

1. VpcGatewayAttachement
2. PublicSubnet2
3. InternetGateway
4. Vpc.

I tried to manually delete these, but it seems that yet another resource `BastionHostSshNetworkInterface` (of type `AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface`) has not actually been destroyed.

I cannot detach nor destroy the interface. When trying to detach the interface via console (web page) on my master/admin account I am getting an error:

> Failed to detach the network interface. API error: "You do not have permission to access the specified resource."

When trying to detach via CLI via:

```
aws ec2 detach-network-interface --attachment-id eni-attach-03e1... --force
```

I am getting similar error:

> An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DetachNetworkInterface operation: You do not have permission to access the specified resource.

I tried granting myself various polices, e.g. `AWSNetworkManagerFullAccess` and `AmazonEC2FullAccess`.

How can grant myself or my CLI user rights to particular network interface, so that I could detach and/or destroy it?

Comment: check `Cloudtrail` there must be an error message there, which permissions you might need or why you are not able to delete that specific resource.

Comment: Is the interface still attached to your bastion host instance, or has that one been cleaned up completely?

Comment: Interface is not attached to bastion host. From what I can see bastion host has been deleted successfully. When I check the interface in AWS console (web page) there is no value in "Instance ID" column. However, if this is any hint, the interface still has one Public IP but I am not able to disassociate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was that before deleting the stack I was playing with Kubernetes and setting up a service. Setting up a service on EKS results in Elastic Load Balancer being created. I did not delete my Kubernetes environment before deleting the stack, and the ELB was left orphaned but connected to VPC and prevented it from being deleted.